# Can't build gobject--introspection-1.70.0 on debian stretch

Tags: linux, debian, glib, gobject

Because debian stretch have old package of [gobject-introspection](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gobject-introspection),i needed to update this.
But when i tryed to build, i got next message:

```
FAILED: gir/GLib-2.0.gir
/home/user/gobject-introspection-1.70.0/_build/tools/g-ir-scanner --output=gir/GLib-2.0.gir --no-libtool --quiet --reparse-validate --add-include-path /home/user/gobject-introspection-1.70.0/_build/gir --add-include-path /home/user/gobject-introspection-1.70.0/gir --identifier-prefix=G --symbol-prefix=g --symbol-prefix=glib --c-include=glib.h --namespace=GLib --nsversion=2.0 --library=glib-2.0 --library=gobject-2.0 --external-library --pkg=glib-2.0 --cflags-begin -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -DGLIB_COMPILATION -D__G_I18N_LIB_H__ -DGETTEXT_PACKAGE=Dummy --cflags-end /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/glib-types.h /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-unix.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/garray.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gasyncqueue.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gatomic.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gbacktrace.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gbase64.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gbitlock.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gbookmarkfile.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gbytes.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gcharset.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gchecksum.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gconvert.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gdataset.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gdate.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gdatetime.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gdir.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/genviron.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gerror.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gfileutils.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/ggettext.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/ghash.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/ghmac.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/ghook.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/ghostutils.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n-lib.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/giochannel.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gkeyfile.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glib-typeof.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glist.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmain.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmappedfile.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmarkup.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmem.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmessages.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gnode.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/goption.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gpattern.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gpoll.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gprimes.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gprintf.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gqsort.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gquark.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gqueue.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/grand.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/grcbox.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/grefcount.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/grefstring.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gregex.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gscanner.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gsequence.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gshell.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gslice.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gslist.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gspawn.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstdio.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstrfuncs.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstring.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstringchunk.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstrvbuilder.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtestutils.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gthreadpool.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtimer.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtimezone.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtrashstack.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtree.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gunicode.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/guri.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gurifuncs.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/guuid.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gvariant.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gvarianttype.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gversion.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gversionmacros.h /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gwin32.h ../gir/glib-2.0.c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/gobject-introspection-1.70.0/_build/tools/g-ir-scanner", line 98, in <module>
    from giscanner.scannermain import scanner_main
  File "/home/user/gobject-introspection-1.70.0/_build/giscanner/scannermain.py", line 35, in <module>
    from giscanner.ast import Include, Namespace
  File "/home/user/gobject-introspection-1.70.0/_build/giscanner/ast.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .sourcescanner import CTYPE_TYPEDEF, CSYMBOL_TYPE_TYPEDEF
  File "/home/user/gobject-introspection-1.70.0/_build/giscanner/sourcescanner.py", line 34, in <module>
    from giscanner._giscanner import SourceScanner as CSourceScanner
```

**ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_date_copy**

I know about required version glib >= 2.56.
I build it too and install from latest(**2.70**) source, but the error remains.

```
user@debian-stretch:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig  /gobject-2.0.pc  
prefix=/usr  
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  
includedir=${prefix}/include  

Name: GObject  
Description: GLib Type, Object, Parameter and Signal Library  
Version: 2.70.0  
Requires: glib-2.0  
Requires.private: libffi >=  3.0.0  
Libs: -L${libdir} -lgobject-2.0  
Cflags: -I${includedir}  

user@debian-stretch:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig  /glib-2.0.pc  
prefix=/usr  
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  
includedir=${prefix}/include  

bindir=${prefix}/bin  
glib_genmarshal=${bindir}/glib-genmarshal  
gobject_query=${bindir}/gobject-query  
glib_mkenums=${bindir}/glib-mkenums  

Name: GLib  
Description: C Utility Library  
Version: 2.70.0  
Requires.private: libpcre >=  8.31  
Libs: -L${libdir} -lglib-2.0  
Libs.private: -pthread -lm  
Cflags: -I${includedir}/glib-2.0 -I${libdir}/glib-2.0/include
```

Can you help with it trouble?

**UPD**
i read again [this post](https://medium.com/@Aenon/glib-symbol-lookup-bug-in-debian-or-ubuntu-def678dab5a6) and i had seen next thing:
default **libglib2.0-0** package install some libs on to another path, in: **/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/**

After that i tryed find it's on my instance, and got next out:

```
user@debian-stretch:~$ sudo find / -iname '*glib-2.0.*'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/GLib-2.0.typelib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7000.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7000.0-gdb.py
/usr/share/gir-1.0/GLib-2.0.gir
/usr/share/aclocal/glib-2.0.m4
/usr/local/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7000.0-gdb.py
/usr/local/share/aclocal/glib-2.0.m4
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5000.3
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
/home/user/glib-2.70.0/m4macros/glib-2.0.m4
/home/user/glib-2.70.0/_build/glib/libglib-2.0.so.0.7000.0.p
/home/user/glib-2.70.0/_build/glib/libglib-2.0.so
/home/user/glib-2.70.0/_build/glib/libglib-2.0.so.0.7000.0-gdb.py
/home/user/glib-2.70.0/_build/glib/libglib-2.0.so.0
/home/user/glib-2.70.0/_build/meson-private/glib-2.0.pc
/home/user/gobject-introspection-1.70.0/gir/glib-2.0.c
/home/user/gobject-introspection-1.70.0/subprojects/glib/m4macros/glib-2.0.m4
/home/user/packaging-glib/glib-2.70.0/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so
/home/user/packaging-glib/glib-2.70.0/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
/home/user/packaging-glib/glib-2.70.0/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7000.0
/home/user/packaging-glib/glib-2.70.0/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
/home/user/packaging-glib/glib-2.70.0/usr/share/aclocal/glib-2.0.m4
```

After remove this libs:
**/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5000.3**
**/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0**
building continue.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely don't delete the GLib libraries in `/lib`. Since your package manager installed them there, other packages may expect to find them there, and so this may break your system down the line. (And since Debian Stretch is so old, with a GLib version of 2.50, it may even cause problems if you install GLib 2.70 systemwide.)

If you must install 2.70 systemwide, then I'd recommend building it with exactly the same configuration as the system version would. You can find the standard configuration options [here](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/debhelper/-/blob/main/lib/Debian/Debhelper/Buildsystem/meson.pm#L54-64) and the options specific to GLib [here](https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/glib/-/blob/debian/master/debian/rules#L219-240). The options for gobject-introspection you can find in a similar place.

Even better, if you need to develop something using a GLib and gobject-introspection version that is not supported on your host system, would be to use some form of container technology. Either a runtime like Flatpak, or a "pet container" with a development environment, like [Toolbox](https://github.com/containers/toolbox/).

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I am trying to use these build options next times.